# Ruby Integer#chr vs Python chr() different results

Tags: python, ruby, encoding, character-encoding

I'm trying to write the RC4 encryption algorithm in Ruby. The problem I have is that some ordinal values get mangled or differently translated when I convert it to a character to get its binary value.

For example,

```rb
>> 27.chr
=> "\e"
=> 27.chr
>> 27.chr.encoding
=> #<Encoding:US-ASCII>
>> 27.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)
=> "\e"
```

On the other hand, using python3 or javascript(`String.fromCharCode()`), it gives a different value (which the value I need)

```py
>>> chr(27)
'\x1b'
```

Of course, this issue affects the final encrypted string where I can't decrypt it with other implementations that are being written with other languages.

The RC4 encryption code

```rb
def rc4_encrypt(key, str)
  s = (0..256).to_a
  j = 0

  (0..256).each do |i|
    j = (j + s[i] + key[i % key.size].ord) % 256
    s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
  end
  j = 0
  y = 0
  o = []
  str.each_char do |c|
    j = (j + 1) % 256
    y = (y + s[j]) % 256
    s[j], s[y] = s[y], s[j]
    r = (c.ord ^ s[(s[j] + s[y]) % 256])
    o << r.chr 
  end
  o.join
end
```

**Notes:**

- I tried some other Ruby implementations and I'm getting the same issue.
- I know that RC4 is a very weak algorithm.

Thank you!

Comment: "\e" == "\x1b". It is merely a different syntax in a string literal, but it is the exact same character. It is not printable, so you're getting the code representation. You're worrying about  having bought a ticket to a Marshall Mathers concert, but some guy called Eminem showed up instead.

Comment: The issue shows up because you're letting console output your string, which uses `#inspect`, instead of `puts` or `write`, which would show you what the string really looks like. tl;dr: The string is the same; the output is different.

Comment: Hint: Try `"\x1b"` in IRB.

Comment: @KINGSABRI : Why do you think that 27 is different from \x1b? Do the math: 1b (hex) to decimal is 1*16+11, which for me is 27.

Comment: @user1934428 yeah I know what are you referring to, without calculation (`27.to_s(16)`). the problem is when I use `Interger#chr` I get a different result. 

However, based on @Amanan and @tadman, it's the same value. However, the result of the encryption differs.

maybe there is something wrong with the encryption calculation itself?

Comment: To see why the Python-implementation is different from the Ruby one, we would to have see both, but you posted only the Ruby variant. If we can't find out via static analysis, you would probably have to insert print statements to show the intermediate results.

Comment: I think my problem analysis was wrong. The problem is not in `chr`, it's in the encoding. When python utf-8 an undefined string, python prepends "\xc2" before the byte itself. Unlike ruby, it raises an error. However, if I enforce the utf-8 encoding it ruby, the encryption will generate a totally different value.